# Computing a symbolic sum

Tags: summation, symbolic-computation, summation-method

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210306/evaluating-another-symbolic-sum) I asked the question below, of the *Mathematica* community. I would be just as happy to solve it other ways -- even analytically! :-)

---

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209858/evaluating-a-symbolic-sum) I asked about a symbolic sum, and received three very insightful replies (from: მამუკა ჯიბლაძე, Carl Woll and Dr. Wolfgang Hintze) which did the trick. (Thank you again!)

Currently I am trying to solve a different symbolic sum, which in a general format is:

```
Sum[(-1 + p)^s p^t, {p, 2, m}, Assumptions -> (s | t) \[Element] Integers]
```

Each factor alone would lead to Harmonic numbers or Zeta functions, respectively. However, in this form, the sum returns unevaluated. I tried all of the three methods suggested previously (including integrating instead of differentiating, in one of the approaches), to no avail.

More specifically, the sum is:

```
Sum[(-1 + p)^(-1 + i - k) p^(-i + n), {p, 2, m}]
```

with `m` and `n` any positive integers, `i` values running from 1 to `n-1` and `k` from 0 to `i-1`.

I also tried replacing the `(p-1)^s` with its own sum (with the binomial coefficient, etc.) and switching the order of the summations -- also to no avail.

Thank you for any direction, and for your time.

Comment: Could you write the sum using mathematical symbols. Not everybody is proficient in the Mathematica language.

Comment: @BernardMassé I read that as $$ \sum_{p=2}^m(p-1 )^{i - k-1} p^{n-i}$$

Comment: Thank you Hagen von Eitzen, and sorry Bernard Massé. (I am a LaTeXnician for over three decades, but did not immediately see how to enter the mathematical notation in Markdown. I see it now.)